# Ng-repeat not loading each item in the array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

So I'm trying to repeat some posts called updates.

```
<div ng-repeat"update in updates.updates">   
{{update.content}}
</div>
```

If I do {{updates}} I get this (notice it's an array in updates. So I'm trying to repeat updates.updates).

```
{"updates":
[{"_id":"54ad53cc63b627c111fec6ac","content":"Post","author":"5485ef86028950a880f7f878","date":"2015-01-07T15:42:04.768Z"},
{"_id":"54ad547840f3d5db11c6da63","content":"sad","author":"5485ef86028950a880f7f878","date":"2015-01-07T15:44:56.395Z"},
{"_id":"54ad54b987cd37e611761d4e","content":"Soadfasdf","author":"5485ef86028950a880f7f878","date":"2015-01-07T15:46:01.066Z"},
{"_id":"54ad55345326d0f911427ea0","content":"asdf","author":"5485ef86028950a880f7f878","date":"2015-01-07T15:48:04.717Z"},
{"_id":"54ad6240df3ebc9813364d13","content":"asdf","author":"5485ef86028950a880f7f878","date":"2015-01-07T16:43:44.623Z"}]}
```

So the array is in there... it's working with {{updates}} but not ng-repeat. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Controller code:

```
    function getUpdates() {
        Updates.getUpdates().then(function (data) {
            $scope.updates = data;

        });
    }
```

Here's the express controller:

```
    db.collection('updates', function (err, collection) {
        collection.find({
            author: req.user._id
        }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('updates.get.error', err);
                throw err;
            }
            // they have messages
            if (docs) {
                console.log(docs);
                res.send({
                    updates: docs
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Didnt find updates');
                res.send({
                    updates: []
                });
            }

        }

    )});
```

Comment: please share your controller code and the way data is retrived.

Comment: did you try "update in updates"?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll update the original question.

Comment: Thank you for helping, unobf! update in updates didn't work, either.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ng-repeat missing equal to bracket:

```
<div ng-repeat="update in updates.updates">   
{{update.content}}
</div>
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Unfortunately it's not working for me either. The update in updates.updates is a red font color for some reason. I'm using the Brackets ide and that's not a normal color.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing an equal sign. ng-repeat="